# Deleting the current session with Rack::Session::Cookie

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, and I'm hoping that as soon as I post this someone will shame me with the google search link I was missing :-)

```
enable :sessions

get '/logout' do
  # What goes here to kill the session?
end
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just use

```
session.clear
```

to destroy the session.

Comment: From the OP example it's clear (`enable :sessions`) that they are using Sinatra or a similar ruby framework, yet they asked about deleting the session using `Rack::Session::Cookie` directly. Does the solution provided in this answer applies to that, or is Sinatra/Rails specific? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451392/how-do-i-set-get-session-vars-in-a-rack-app `#session` is a method specific to Sinatra/Rails/... and plain rack applications don’t have it. If this is true then, does anybody know what's the correct rack-only way to deal with this?

Comment: not working for me, tried it a couple of times. I have a very simple app using `enable :sessions`

Comment: @jj_ Nope, `sinatra` and `rails` use rack middleware.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you create your session. Simply you have to nulify session entry. Here is simple example, how to create and destroy sessions.

```
  get '/login' do
    session[:username] = params[:username]
    "logged in as #{session[:username]}"
  end

  get '/logout' do
    old_user = session[:username]
    session[:username] = nil
    "logged out #{old_user}"
  end
```

You can also check this example: https://gist.github.com/131401

Comment: Hmm, I had tried that, but the rack.session cookie still exists after I "log out".

Comment: @ecoffey are you sure its the same cookie? If you use `session.clear` it'll likely be a new session, but the old one will havw been destroyed. Nil-ing session key(s) might keep the original cookie but be devoid of any value(s).