# How do I set/get session vars in a Rack app?

Tags: ruby, session, rack

```
use Rack::Session::Pool
...
session[:msg]="Hello Rack"
```

EDIT: The word session doesn't seem to resolve. I included the Session pool middleware in my config.ru, and try to set a variable in an ERB file (I'm using Ruby Serve) and it complains "undefined local variable or method `session'"

Thanks!

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? is the session helper not working at all, or just is it that session[:msg] isn't set? what does session.inspect give you?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`session` is a method that is part of some web frameworks, for example [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20Sessions) and [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session) both have `session` methods. Plain `rack` applications don’t have a `session` method, unless you add one yourself.

The session hash is stored in the rack env hash under the key `rack.session`, so you can access it like this (assuming you’ve named the rack environment to your app `env`):

```
env['rack.session'][:msg]="Hello Rack"
```

Alternatively, you could use Rack’s built in [`request` object](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb), like this:

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
request.session[:msg]="Hello Rack"
```

Comment: But then why you can also do: `request.env['rack.session'][:msg]="Hello Rack"` ? If I understand this correctly, `Rack::Request` is a wrapper around `env` but if so, then how does `request.env[...` make sense? I can't get my head around it :\

Comment: @jj_`Rack::Request` is a wrapper around the `env` hash that allows you to do various common things easily, and it also provides access to the `env` hash n case you need to use it directly for something that `Rack::Request` doesn’t provide.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that and explaining... however, isn't the fact that `#env` is available on `Rack::Request` a bit confusing? `Rack::Request `encapsulates `env`, but at the same time `#env` is available to `Rack::Request` to provide `env` in its raw form.. **why so when the original `env` is still available everywhere, already?** Maybe from a class designer point of view is just to make `Rack::Request` more feature-complete on its own? Just trying to understand the rationale behind it... Thanks!

Comment: @jj_ Yes you could just use `env` directly and not bother with `Rack::Response`, but the class provides methods like `scheme` and `host` which you would need to look up various headers and how they are used in order to replicate, as well as easy access to the request parameters (including parsing query strings), so it’s just more convenient to use.

Comment: I don't find this works with `rack 1.6` and rails `4.2`.  I cannot find an interface that works.

Comment: I had to do this: ```env['rack.session.options'][:skip] = true``` to get it to save

Answer (score 0):

You need to load  `rack::session` module next probably cookie like here
http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html

This like explains it with example.