# Are there any basic examples of Rack::Session::Cookie usage?

Tags: ruby, passenger, rack

I can't find any simple examples for using `Rack::Session::Cookie` and would like to be able to store information in a cookie, and access it on later requests and have it expire.

These are the only examples I've been able to find:

- [How do I set/get session vars in a Rack app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451392/how-do-i-set-get-session-vars-in-a-rack-app)
- http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html

Here's what I'm getting:

```
 use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                               :domain => 'foo.com',
                               :path => '/',
                               :expire_after => 2592000,
                               :secret => 'change_me'
```

And then setting/retrieving:

```
env['rack.session'][:msg]="Hello Rack"
```

I can't find any other guides or examples for the setup of this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

You have already setup cookie in your question. I am not sure if you means something else by "setup".

Instead of `env['rack.session']` you can use `session[KEY]` for simplification.

```
session[:key] = "vaue" # will set the value
session[:key] # will return the value
```

Simple Sinatra example

```
require 'sinatra'
set :sessions, true
get '/' do
    session[:key_set] = "set"
    "Hello"
end
get "/sess" do
    session[:key_set]
end
```

**Update**

I believe it wasn't working for you because you had set invalid domain. So I had to strip that off `:domain => 'foo.com',`. BTW Sinatra wraps Rack cookie and exposes `session` helper. So above code worked fine for me. I believe following code should work as expected.

```
require 'sinatra'
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
  :expire_after => 2592000,
  :secret => 'change_me'
get '/' do
  msg = params["msg"] || "not set"
  env["rack.session"][:msg] = msg
  "Hello"
end
get "/sess" do
  request.session["msg"]
end
```

- set session value `msg` access root or `/` defaults to 'not set' if you pass `?msg=someSTring` it should set msg with new value.
- access `/sess` to check whats in session.

You can take some cues from [How do I set/get session vars in a Rack app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451392/how-do-i-set-get-session-vars-in-a-rack-app)

Comment: The issue I have discovered with this is if I restart the Web Service, the session is dead, and the set Session isn't saved in the cookie. 

So if you hit '/', restart sinatra, then hit /sess, you'll not return any information.

Comment: Note that above code is for **Sinatra** and it is slightly different from the code snippet you have posted but basically it wraps Rack Cookie internally AFAIK. I haven't worked on Rack directly so I had to spend some time to figure this out. Please refer to updated answer above.

Comment: I think you should clarify the difference between `env["rack.session"][:msg]` and `request.session["msg"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example below. It might give you good idea

http://chneukirchen.org/repos/rack/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb