# How to Log users out, after Logging in with Github

Tags: session, github, oauth, sinatra, github-api

I've set up functionality to "Log in with Github" using Oauth, as described [in this tutorial](http://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/). It's working great, but I can't figure out how to give them a button to log out.

I've tried providing a button imitating [Github's logout form](https://github.com/logout) (sending a POST request to https://github.com/logout) but it gives the user a Github error page with a Status code: 422 Unprocessable Entity.

I'm using Octokit.rb with Sinatra. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would that SO answer be helpful? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225298/335418

Comment: Not really, since like that poster, I don't want to store their user credentials or have them re-enter them. I know it's possible without user creds... the [sinatra_auth_github](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra_auth_github) gem (which I'm not using) [has logout functionality built in](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra_auth_github/search?q=logout%21&ref=cmdform).

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that I need to expire their login session. I was using Rack::Session with Sinatra, so in my case, this was the solution:

```
get '/logout' do
  session.clear
end
```

See also: [Deleting the current session with Rack::Session::Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252800/deleting-the-current-session-with-racksessioncookie)